# Stream an object, Send request with completable future and assign result to the object

Tags: java-8, java-stream, completable-future

I have a list of Object Signers. For each of this signers I need to make a ReST request to get their signing URL. I am trying to do it with completable futures so all ReST requests can be send in parallel, then I need to set that URL in each of the signers, so this operation will not return new signers just update the ones that I am already iterating.

I have this code that is already working, but I think that could be improved.

```
 List<Signer> signers=......

 List<CompletableFuture> futures = signers.stream()
          .map(signer -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(signer))
          .map(future -> future.thenCombine(       CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> signatureService.getSigningUrl(future.join().getSignerId())),
                           (signer, url) -> {
                               signer.setUrl(url);
                               return url;
                           }
                   )).collect(toList());

           futures.stream()
                   .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                    .collect(toList());
```

Could I replace this

```
 futures.stream()
   .map(CompletableFuture::join)
   .collect(toList());
```

With this?

```
futures.stream().forEach(CompletableFuture::join)
```

I don't like to return that because it was already used setting it in the signer. and don't like the second `collect(toList())` because I am not trying to collect anything at that time.

What other implementation would you use?

Comment: have you looked into using parallel streams? It'll make the rest calls asynchronously and assign the value to your `Signer` object before it collects.

Comment: In Spring in action book they make some suggestions on when to use streams and completable futures.

 If you’re doing computation-heavy operations with no I/O, then the Stream interface gives the simplest implementation and one likely to be the most efficient (if all threads are compute-bound, then there’s no point in having more threads than processor cores).

Comment:  On the other hand, if your parallel units of work involve waiting for I/O (including network connections), then CompletableFutures give more flexibility and the ability to match the number of threads to the wait/computer, or W/C, ratio as discussed previously. Another reason to avoid using parallel streams when I/O waits are involved in the stream-processing pipeline is that the laziness of streams can make it harder to reason about when the waits actually happen.

Answer (score 1):

No. `futures.stream().forEach(CompletableFuture::join)` returns `void` whereas `futures.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(toList());` returns `CompletableFuture<List<?>>`.

They both are meant for different purposes. But both does one thing common(i.e, blocks the main thread till all the completablefutures are finished).

I would write your same code bit differently using CompletableFuture.allOf.

```
    Stream<CompletableFuture<String>> streamFutures = signers.stream()
            .map(signer -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(signer))
            .map(future -> future.thenCombine(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> signatureService.getSigningUrl(future.join().getSignerId())),
                    (signer, url) -> {
                        signer.setUrl(url);
                        return url;
                    }
            ));

    CompletableFuture<String> [] futureArr = streamFutures.toArray(size -> new CompletableFuture[size]);
    List<CompletableFuture<String>> futures = Arrays.asList(futureArr);

    CompletableFuture<Void> allFuturesVoid = CompletableFuture.allOf(futureArr);
    allFuturesVoid.join();
    CompletableFuture<List<?>> allCompletableFuture = allFuturesVoid.thenApply(future -> futures.stream().map(completableFuture -> completableFuture.join()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

There is good tutorial here https://m-hewedy.blogspot.com/2017/02/completablefutureallof-that-doenst.html and here https://medium.com/@senanayake.kalpa/fantastic-completablefuture-allof-and-how-to-handle-errors-27e8a97144a0.